# HOw do I limit array to a certain number?

Tags: php, mysql

actually what I am trying to do is store incoming searches in a database and then display to a web page limiting to a certain number say 10 with the heading of "Recent Searches". if you LIMIT 10 in database query then It stops after 10. so thought will cut off loop but both case it stops at 10. so after that what ever searches happens it wont update it. is there any one can help me in this situation??

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY regtime DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<img src='bullet.gif' align='absmiddle' class='col1ab'><a class='col1ab' href=".$row['web']." >www.".$row['web']."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: He's trying to do what `LIMIT 10` does in a SQL statement in the `while` loop instead.

Comment: What is the reason against `LIMIT`?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Sometimes people like to retrieve all results for a count (via num_rows), but that's a very unsophisticated way of doing it.

Comment: actually what I am trying to do is store incoming searches in a database and then display to a web page limiting to a certain number say 10 with the heading of "Recent Searches" if you LIMIT 10 in database query then It stops after 10. so thought will cut of loop but both case it stops at 10. so after that what ever searches happens it wont update it. is there any one can help me in this situation??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY regtime DESC");
while($count < 10 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $count++;
  echo "<img src='bullet.gif' align='absmiddle' class='col1ab'><a class='col1ab' href=".$row['web']." >www.".$row['web']."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: +1 Just a nitpick but I would put the $count comparison **before** the fetch so that it will short circuit, saving a read.

Answer (score 1):

Limit what array? I don't see an array in your code. If you want to limit the number of echos you make, you can count a variable and then break once you reach 10, like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY regtime DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($i++ >= 10) break;
  echo "<img src='bullet.gif' align='absmiddle' class='col1ab'><a class='col1ab' href=".$row['web']." >www.".$row['web']."</a><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY regtime DESC");

$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<img src='bullet.gif' align='absmiddle' class='col1ab'><a class='col1ab' href=".$row['web']." >www.".$row['web']."</a><br>";

  if (++$counter === 10) break;
}
```

The loop increments the value of `$counter` variable and when it becomes 10, the `break` keyword exits out of the `while` loop there by giving you just 10 iterations.

Comment: I would remove `if ($counter === 10) break;` and replace `$counter++;` with `if (++$counter === 10) break;`.  That should save the extra read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not the requested answer but ...

Don't store searches. Make your data efficiently searchable.(search friendly schema,index, partitioning, more hardware)

reasons:
query data is no longer real time if read from query table 
more space is needed for duplicate data in query table 
more io is required to fill the query table

use 2 queries or estimate (how critical is accuracy?(since it is stored, the number is most likely not accurate))

"SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY regtime DESC" with LIMIT(10)
"SELECT count(*) FROM query..."

Answer (score 0):

Why did no one come up with:

SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY regtime DESC LIMIT 0,6